# SSH Password prompt for a password after ssh keys are configured

Tags: ssh

Although I placed my public key on the remote machine yet I am still getting the ssh password prompt, here's my `ssh -vv` output (just the last rows) that might help:

```
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/lior/.ssh/id_rsa  <-- THAT's MY PRIVATE KEY!
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lior/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lior/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lior/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Important: I am able to ssh to other machines without password after doing the same procedure, so I assume the problem is on the specific remote machine (which runs on CentOS 6).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd create an ~/.ssh/config file and add an entry for your server. https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: The key is rejected by the server. Make sure the server is properly configured to accept your key (permissions, SELinux labels).

Comment: Set verbose logging on on the server if you have access. If you don't, ask the sysadmin to check what it has to say.

Answer (score 1):

In the remote user's home dir:

- who is the owner of the homedir ?
- who is the owner of homedir/.ssh ?
- who is the owner of homedir/.ssh/authorized_keys

Which is the 
access rights on ~, ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

to permissive read and or write rights on ~/.ssh/authorized_keys will
make sshd distrust that file !

Comment: I agree with you, most likely this is a remote config issue, like wrong permissions on home dir, .ssh or authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve this problem 100% but try this out. Create a file in the directory `~/.ssh/config`. When you vim into the config file, you can try the following:

```
Host <host_name_of_server>
HostName <ip_address_of_server>
User <user_created_for_server>
Port 22
PasswordAuthentication No
IdentityFile <path_to_key>
```

So once this has been added, you can now do the following:

```
ssh <host_name_of_server>
```

When you SSH into the Host that you assigned your server, this will force it not to prompt for a password. Let me know how this pans out.

Comment: /Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: host:
/Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: hostname:
/Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: user:
/Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: port:
/Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: passwordauthentication:
/Users/lior/.ssh/config: line 6: Bad configuration option: identityfile:

Comment: Yaiks How do i format my code in a comment

Comment: I think the `:` are not needed

Comment: Yeah your right.. ill adjust my answer